# How much information is lost when I average integers?

Tags: c++, math, average

Using C++, as this takes place on a microcontroller. My inputs are six int16_t. I cast them to int32_t so I can add them together, and then divide by 6, then store the result in an int16_t for transmission. Something like the following, and assume someRandomInt is exactly that, a random 16-bit integer each line:

```
int16_t one = someRandomInt;
int16_t two = someRandomInt;
int16_t three = someRandomInt;
int16_t four = someRandomInt;
int16_t five = someRandomInt;
int16_t six = someRandomInt;

int32_t sum = (int32_t)one + (int32_t)two + (int32_t)three + (int32_t)four + (int32_t)five + (int32_t)six;

int16_t result = (int16_t)(sum / 6);
```

I do this 16384 times per second and then perform I/Q Demodulation on the result array.

Playing around with it in Python, I've calculated that across the entire range of possibilities for the sum (-196601 to 196601) that when I divide by 6 and take the decimal parts of everything, the average decimal part is 0.417±0.285. My intuition is that that's what I'm *losing* when I do the math above. Is that correct? I'm concerned about when sensor values are close to zero.

Comment: Are you looking for like a measurement in bits of entropy?

Comment: What are you using this calculated loss to do? That might help us inform the best approach.

Comment: @JohnFilleau the inputs come from six identical sensors, and I'm averaging them to improve SNR. I'm trying to get a sense of how much information I'm losing when I do this, since I'll need to report that as part of the measurement uncertainty.

Comment: Okay so your final output will be a range of possible values. "The average was actually somewhere between 100 and 101" or something like that

Comment: What's the "noise floor" for lack of a better work on these sensors? They may vary wildly enough that the difference between an average of 100 or 100 + 5/6 doesn't matter.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I'll amend the OP to reflect this, but I'm doing this 16384 times per second and then doing IQ demodulation. How would that error propagate?

Comment: Sorry for the previous patronising answer ;-) I'm wondering if `(int16_t)((sum + 3) / 6);` would give you a better measure?

Comment: I think the thing to do is acknowledge on the distant end that when you receive a value, it actually represents 6 possible values (n, n + 1/6, n + 2/6, ...) except for 0 which represents 11 possible values. Carry this absolute uncertainty through to the end, and combine it with your other errors (absolute or relative) to determine the final probabalistic range. You probably want to give your final answer to 1, 2, or 3 std-dev right? I don't know how IQ demodulation works, so I don't know if this is a realistic approach for that.

Comment: @Bathsheba: It's likely that the signal has zero bias (signed). In that case you introduce a DC bias by adding on average 0.5. C++ rounds towards zero, so the original form underestimates the amplitude.

Comment: @BenS.: If your signal is slow enough, it may make sense to keep track of your rounding error and carry that over to the next measurement. That is to say, you remember `sum%6` and add that to the next sum.

Comment: @MSalters My signal typically has a frequency of 1227.6 Hz, while I'm sampling at 16383 Hz. Does that qualify as "slow enough"?

Comment: @BenS. : Should be OK, but you might refine it a bit further. If sum%6 >= 3, then add 1 to the current value and carry (sum%6)-6. That is to say, carry values [-3,2] instead of [0,5]. That removes a small bias.

Answer (score 1):

I may not understand the question.

There is no information lost when you calculate "sum", correct?

Therefore, any information lost comes in when you divide the integer by six.

So it doesn't matter how many sensors go into the sum or how many times you sample them.

It just matters that you are dividing a number by six.  When you divide an integer by an integer you get truncation and in this case that will happen 5 out of the 6 times.

5 divided by 6 is simply .8333.  Half of that is .417.  So your experimental results appear correct.

Comment: There's indeed no information lost in the sum. That's done in 32 bits, but you only need 3 extra bits for 6 numbers. So 16+3=19 < 32.

Comment: It was a rhetorical question.  :)